# Unwanted white space on left side of Tikz Picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, white-space

I am trying to recreate this:
[image: Banner I am trying to recreate]

This is what I have so far:
[image: My Recreation]

You might not be able to tell from this image, but there is some white space to the left of the picture, and I'm not sure why.  I was wondering if someone could explain where it is coming from!

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\colorlet{Random0}{Yellow!50!DarkKhaki}
\colorlet{Random1}{Yellow!50!DarkKhaki}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usepackage[ttdefault=true]{AnonymousPro}
%\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{contour}

\begin{document}
    \contourlength{0.1pt} %how thick each copy is

\begin{tikzpicture}[yshift=-3cm]
\path[fill=%DodgerBlue,
CornflowerBlue,
%DeepSkyBlue!70!MidnightBlue,
path fading=east] (0,0) rectangle(\paperwidth,3cm);
\foreach \x in {35,...,70}{
    \foreach \y in {0,...,7} 
    \pgfmathsetmacro\Random{random(0,1)}
    \node[draw=none,color=Random\Random,anchor=south west,font=\ttfamily\bfseries] 
    at (\x*.3cm,\y*.33cm) 
    {\Random};};
\node[anchor=south west,font=\LARGE\bfseries,yshift=0.7cm]{%\contour{Black}
    {\textcolor{OliveDrab}{$
\text{z-value}=\frac{1.752\times .123}{\sqrt{.123^2\times .267^2+1.752^2\times .011^2}}=\frac{.215496}{\sqrt{.015\times .082+3.07\times .0001}}
$}}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The white space comes from the stuff before `\begin{tikzpicture}`. Move `
`\contourlength{0.1pt}` to the left, add `%` right after it without space and kill the empty line. An even easier option is to use `\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass[12pt,tikz]{standalone}` at the very beginning of the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The white space comes from stuff you have between `\begin{document}` and `\begin{tikzpicture}`. You can just move `\contourlength{0.1pt}` before `\begin{document}`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\colorlet{Random0}{Yellow!50!DarkKhaki}
\colorlet{Random1}{Yellow!50!DarkKhaki}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usepackage[ttdefault=true]{AnonymousPro}
\usepackage{contour}
\contourlength{0.1pt} %how thick each copy is
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[fill=%DodgerBlue,
CornflowerBlue,
%DeepSkyBlue!70!MidnightBlue,
path fading=east] (0,0) rectangle(\paperwidth,3cm);
\foreach \x in {35,...,70}{
    \foreach \y in {0,...,7} 
    \pgfmathsetmacro\Random{random(0,1)}
    \node[draw=none,color=Random\Random,anchor=south west,font=\ttfamily\bfseries] 
    at (\x*.3cm,\y*.33cm) 
    {\Random};};
\node[anchor=south west,font=\LARGE\bfseries,yshift=0.7cm]{%\contour{Black}
    {\textcolor{OliveDrab}{$
\text{z-value}=\frac{1.752\times .123}{\sqrt{.123^2\times .267^2+1.752^2\times .011^2}}=\frac{.215496}{\sqrt{.015\times .082+3.07\times .0001}}
$}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Or you can use `standalone` to crop. To this end, add `tikz` to the options of standalone, which loads `tikz` and makes the `tikzpicture` a standalone environment. In order to avoid an option clash for `xcolor`, you need `\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames}{xcolor}`.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass[12pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\colorlet{Random0}{Yellow!50!DarkKhaki}
\colorlet{Random1}{Yellow!50!DarkKhaki}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usepackage[ttdefault=true]{AnonymousPro}
%\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{contour}

\begin{document}
    \contourlength{0.1pt} %how thick each copy is

\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[fill=%DodgerBlue,
CornflowerBlue,
%DeepSkyBlue!70!MidnightBlue,
path fading=east] (0,0) rectangle(\paperwidth,3cm);
\foreach \x in {35,...,70}{
    \foreach \y in {0,...,7} 
    \pgfmathsetmacro\Random{random(0,1)}
    \node[draw=none,color=Random\Random,anchor=south west,font=\ttfamily\bfseries] 
    at (\x*.3cm,\y*.33cm) 
    {\Random};};
\node[anchor=south west,font=\LARGE\bfseries,yshift=0.7cm]{%\contour{Black}
    {\textcolor{OliveDrab}{$
\text{z-value}=\frac{1.752\times .123}{\sqrt{.123^2\times .267^2+1.752^2\times .011^2}}=\frac{.215496}{\sqrt{.015\times .082+3.07\times .0001}}
$}}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you!  Such a silly question...  Haven't used Tikz very much!